# How to get access to window elements

Tags: c#, macos, user-interface, appkit, xamarin.mac

I am writing a program that will get user inputs and store data about GUI elements, which user has clicked in desktop applications.

I need data from GUI like: element name, element description, class, element parent, children, etc.

Code is written on C#. As i found out, i can use Xamarin.Mac to call macOs AppKit API from C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsapplication?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14).
Now the question is what do i call to get this data?

Or is there any alternative way to get this data?

Comment: Did you want to enable accessibility features like VoiceOver for your application? If so, you can use [accessibilityUserInputLabels](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/3197989-accessibilityuserinputlabels?language=objc) to mark your controls and call them locally, you can refer to this document for accessibility features:https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXmodel.html

Comment: I am writing a program like VoiceOver. But instead of naming objects aloud, my program logs everything in a file

Answer (score -1):

First, from the XAML part, make sure the objects have a name defined and that they are public after you can call the variable name in the C# code, and from there put a dot (".") many methods, attributes, and options will appear, for example, you are asking about the children, you could use

```
var titleBarChildre = AppTitleBar.Children.ToList();
```

etc.

Comment: No, this answer does not apply to this question. The question is about `Xamarin.Mac`, which is 1:1 with Apple's Objective C API. This answer is only meaningful for `Xamarin.Forms`, which uses `xaml` to describe UI elements.